# Что тут не так?

Tags: javascript

Простое сравнение сравнение вроде но, не могу понять что тут не так.

```
function butt() {
  a = prompt('Регистрация!')
  arr_pass = [a]
  if(arr_pass >= 0) {
    setTimeout(avt())
  }
}

function avt() {
  avt_pass = prompt('Авторизация')
  if(avt_pass==arr_pass) {
    alert('+')
  }
}
```

Comment: `arr_pass = [a]` - зачем?  `if(arr_pass >= 0){` возможно  `if(arr_pass.length > 0){` ?

Comment: Поясните, в чем проблема, т.е. что вводите, что ожидаете получить и что получаете.

Comment: К сожалению "не так" здесь все, кроме пары строк. Расскажите чего хочется

Comment: @RomanKonoval я просто хотел чтобы prompt чтобы был место input-a, сделать что-то похожее на форму авторизации и реализовать это так чтобы первый prompt записывался в массив  и потом была проверка на наличие содержимого в массиве, если там что-то есть, тогда запускалась следующая функция которая будет делать тоже самое только без проверки содержимого в  массиве и при успешном сравнении пусть выводиться "+".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const users = [];

signUp.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const login = this.elements.item(0);
    const password = this.elements.item(1);

    if (!login.value || !password.value) return;
    
    users.push({
        login: login.value,
        password: password.value
    });
    
    alert(`Пользователь [${login.value}] успешно зарегистрирован.`);
    
    login.value = '';
    password.value = '';
}

signIn.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const login = this.elements.item(0);
    const password = this.elements.item(1);

    if (!login.value || !password.value) return;
    
    const find = users.find(user =>
        user.login === login.value &&
        user.password === password.value
    );
    
    if (!find) return;
    
    login.value = '';
    password.value = '';
    
    alert(`Успешно авторизован!`);
}
```

```html
<form id="signUp">
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
<br />
<form id="signIn">
    <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Login" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Авторизоваться</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Как этот код относится к вопросу? Нужно пояснение, иначе это выглядит, как что-то совершенно не относящееся к вопросу.

Comment: @RomanKonoval этот ответ прямо относится к вопросу. Автор вопроса имеет многочисленные синтаксические и логические ошибки, он не понимает как работать с инструментом и не может выстроить свой вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать конкретный ответ. Либо вопрос должен закрыться, либо на него можно оставлять подобный код. По логике кода я понял что автор хотел сделать сохранение пароля и потом проверку его же, я ему предоставил сниппет решающий его вопрос относительно кода. Насчет комментариев, на них не так много времени чтобы оставлять их.